# Golang wails How to send data from go to js when dom ready and window is opened

Tags: go, wails

what i need to do in domReady func or ...?

```
func (a App) domReady(ctx context.Context) {
    
}
```

and in index.html

```
<script></script>
```

Cant understand how to send data from `go` to `js` when dom ready and window is opened

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the Go function you want to call on the event `DOMContentLoaded` as a member function of the `App` structure, for instance:

```
func (a *App) OnDOMContentLoaded(arg1 string) string {
    return arg1;
}
```

After compiling, this function will be available on the "frontend\wailsjs\go\main\App.js" file, and you can import it from your JS/TS files:

```
// assuming your JS file is in "frontend/src".
import {OnDOMContentLoaded} from '../wailsjs/go/main/App';
```

The compiled Go functions imported from JS return a promise with their return value. Then, inside your JS source, you just have to call the imported function on the listener of the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    OnDOMContentLoaded('Hi!').then((result) => alert(result));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this at the golang back end

runtime.EventsEmit(a.ctx, "app:apikey", chatString)

javascript front end below

import { EventsOn } from '../wailsjs/runtime/runtime';

EventsOn('app:apikey', (data) => {

}
hope this helps